# A soft navigation has been detected in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have created simple application two pages, accounts.js and accountView.js. I passed id from accounts.js to accountView.js `<td><FaPencilAlt/> <FaTrashAlt/><Link to={"/accounts"+"/"+x.id }><AiFillDiff/></Link></td>` running localhost fine. If I push to live server not working this error displayed. **A soft navigation has been detected: https://rwood.znapay.in/accounts/1**  could you please check my code
[image]

Accounts.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  Col,
  OverlayTrigger,
  Row,
  Tooltip,
  Table,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { AiFillDiff } from "react-icons/ai";
import "datatables.net-dt/js/dataTables.dataTables.js";
import { AES, enc } from "crypto-js";
import Popup from 'reactjs-popup';
import 'reactjs-popup/dist/index.css';
import "datatables.net-responsive-dt";
import "datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css";
import "react-data-table-component-extensions/dist/index.css";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { TokenContext } from "../AuthProvider";
import $ from "jquery";
import axios from "axios";
import { BsFillEnvelopeFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { FaPencilAlt, FaTrashAlt, FaPlus } from "react-icons/fa";
import { decryptedAccessToken, encryptedAccessToken } from "../../Token";
import Header from '../Header'
import Footer from '../Footer'
const AccountsList = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [formData, setFromdata] = useState({

    account_record: "",

  });


  const handleChange = (e) => {

    setFromdata({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault();


    const encryptedAccessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    const secret_key = '4d3a23fba54bbef1e14dd44ba9591612';
    if (encryptedAccessToken) {
      const decryptedAccessToken = AES.decrypt(encryptedAccessToken, secret_key).toString(enc.Utf8);
      
    fetch('https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/add/record', {
              method: "POST",
              body: JSON.stringify(formData),
              headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            })
              .then((response) => response.json())
              
              .then((response) => { 
                
                  console.log(response)
                  console.log(response.status)
                if (response.message === "record addedd successfully") {
                                  const account_record_new = response.account_type;
                                  
                                  navigate("/accounts/new-account", {
                        
                                    state: { account_record: account_record_new },
                        
                                  });
                        
                                }
              }) 
            } 
             
    };


  const body=$(window).height()
  const header=$("#header").height()
  const nav=$(".navbar").height()
  const footer=$(".footer").height()
  const total_height=header+nav+footer;
  const window_height=body-total_height;
  console.log(total_height)
  console.log(body)
  $(".addAccount").css({"min-height":(window_height)+"px"})
  const userRole = localStorage.getItem("role");
  console.log(userRole);
  const { username ,token} = useContext(TokenContext);
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

 
  useEffect(() => {
   
    fetchData();
  }, [decryptedAccessToken]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/all/accounts', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },        }
      );
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data)
      setDatas(data);
      $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
          $('#tables').DataTable();
        },5)
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  

  return (  
    <>
    <Header/>
    <div className="contactAccount">
      <div className="page-header" id='add-account'>
    <div>
      <h2 className="main-content-title tx-24 mg-b-5">Accounts </h2>
      <ol className="breadcrumb"> 
        <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Dashboard / Accounts</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div className="d-flex">
      <div className="justify-content-center">
        {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-icon-text"> */}
          {/* <Link to='/accounts/add-record'> <i className="fe fe-download-cloud me-2"></i><FaPlus/> Add Account</Link> */}
          <Popup trigger={<button className="button add-accountrecord"> <FaPlus/> Add Account </button>} modal>
    
       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="add-accounts">
        <div className='form-group'>
        <label>Account Record Type</label><br/>
        <select name='account_record' className='form-control' onChange={handleChange} value={formData.account_record}>
          <option >--Select account record type--</option>
          <option value='Agent'>Agent</option>
          <option value='Bank'>Bank</option>
          <option value='Buyer'>Buyer</option>
          
          <option value='Supplier'>Supplier</option>
          <option value='Competitor'>Competitor</option>
          <option value='Employee'>Employee</option>
          <option value='Surveyor'>Surveyor</option>
          </select>
          </div>
          <input type='submit' className="btn btn-primary " value='Submit'/>

          </form>
  </Popup>
        {/* </button> */}
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class='tasks'>
  <table id='tables'>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account Name</th>
      <th>Account Alias</th>
      <th>Account Record Type</th>
      <th>Origin</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Port</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
      <React.Fragment>
      {datas.length > 0 ? (
  datas.map((x) => (
    <tr>
      <td>{x.account_name}</td>
      <td>{x.account_alias}</td>
      <td><span className='account-record'>{x.account_record_type}</span></td>  
      <td>{x.origin}</td>
      <td>{x.phone}</td>
      <td>{x.port}</td> 
      <td><FaPencilAlt/> <FaTrashAlt/><Link to={"/accounts"+"/"+x.id }><AiFillDiff/></Link></td>
    </tr>
  ))
) : (
  <tr>
    <td colSpan="6">No data available</td>
  </tr>
)}

      </React.Fragment>


    </tbody>
    </table>  
    </div> </div>  
    <Footer/>
    </>
  );
};

export default AccountsList;
```

app.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import Header from './components/Header' 
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import OppShipmentList from './components/oppShipmentList'
import Login from './components/Login'
import Price from './components/price'
import AddProduct from './components/addproduct'
// import PriceList from './components/pricelist'
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard'
import Contactus from './components/account/contacts' 
 
import Accountlist from './components/accountlist' 
import AllTcf from './components/alltcf'   
import AccountDetails from './components/accountDetails'   
import Addaccount from './components/account/addaccount'
import Oppourtunity from './components/account/oppourtunity' 
import ResetPassword from './components/ResetPassword' 
import ResetConfirm from './components/ResetConfirm' 
import QuotesList from './components/quoteslist' 
// import AddTcf from './components/addTcf'
import AddOppurtunity from './components/account/addoppurtunity' 
import AllQuotes from './components/account/allQuotes' 
import EditQuote from './components/account/editquote'
import ProductMaster from './components/productMaster/productmaster' 
import Shipment from './components/account/shipment' 
import Quotes from './components/account/quotes'
import AddTcf from './components/addTcf'
import AddPricebook from './components/pricebook/addPricebook'
// newly added 
import AddRecord from './components/accounts/addRecord'
import NewAccount from './components/accounts/newAccount'
import AccountsList from './components/accounts/accounts'
import AccountViewPage from './components/accounts/accountViewPage'
import AddContacts from './components/contact/addContacts';
import ContactLists from './components/contact/contactLists';
import PriceBooklist from './components/pricebook/priceBooklist'
import AddRwoodusers from './components/rwoodusers/addRwoodusers'
import UserList from './components/rwoodusers/userList'
import AddRwoodCompany from './components/rwoodCompany/addRwoodcompany'
import RwoodCompanyLists from './components/rwoodCompany/rwoodCompanyLists'
import AddPrice from './components/price/addPrice'
import UpdatePriceBook from './components/pricebook/updatePricebook'
import PriceLists from './components/price/priceLists'
import AddCotract from './components/contract/addCotract'
import ContractList from './components/contract/contarctList'
import AddOpportunitys from './components/opportunity/addOpportunitys'
import AddRecords from './components/opportunity/addRecords'
import AddQuotes from './components/opportunity/addQuotes'
import OpportunityDetails from './components/opportunity/opportunityDetails'
import OppourtunityList from './components/opportunity/oppourtunityList'
import OpportunityShipmentDetail from './components/opportunity/opportunityShipmentDetail'
import TcfList from './components/tcf/tcfList'
import AddBank from './components/bank/addBank'
import BankLists from './components/bank/BankLists'
import AddoppShippment  from './components/opportunity/addoppShippment'
import ViewOpportunity  from './components/opportunity/viewOpportunity'
import OppShipmentLists from './components/opportunity/oppShipmentList'
import ContractShippment from './components/shippment/contractShippment'
import ContractShippmentList from './components/shippment/contractShippmentList'
import NewProduct from './components/productMaster/addProductMaster'
import ContactViewPage from './components/contact/contactViewPage'
import { AES, enc } from "crypto-js";

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Navigate,
  useLocation,

} from "react-router-dom";
import AuthProvider from "./components/AuthProvider";
import $ from 'jquery'

 

function App() {
  
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
  const location = useLocation();
 
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  return ( 
    <AuthProvider> 
    <Routes>
        <Route
          
          path="/"
          element={isAuthenticated ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />}
          isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
        />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
          element={
            isAuthenticated ? (
              <Navigate
                to={{
                  pathname: location.state?.from || "/",
                  state: { from: location.pathname },
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              <Login/>
            )
          }
        />
        
      <Route
        
        path="/accounts/:id"
        element={isAuthenticated ? <AccountViewPage/> : <Login />}
        isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
      />  
      <Route
        
        path="/accounts/accounts-list"
        element={isAuthenticated ? <AccountsList/> : <Login />}
        isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
      /> 
   
       
      {/* <Route path="/" element={<Login/>}/>
     
      <Route path="/account/addaccount" element={<Addaccount/>}/>
      <Route path="/account/contacts/:id" element={<Contactus/>}/>
      <Route path="/account/contact-list" element={<ContactList/>}/>
      <Route path="/price" element={<Price/>}/> */}
    </Routes> 
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

**What is Soft Navigation**

A soft navigation occurs when content is changed by JavaScript and not by a traditional page load. With a lot of modern front-end frameworks you're not loading an actual page on the server. The routing, like you have here in React, or like you'd see in Angular, is handling loading and changing the page content. You still see changes to the URL which give the appearance of navigating around different files.

But what's really happening is that as you navigate an SPA you're actually "pushing previous URLs in the browser's history to allow the back and forward buttons to work as the user would expect." (See [this reference on soft navigations from chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/soft-navigations-experiment) for more information and the reference to my quote.

It comes down to measuring site and page speed as metrics for scoring a site's performance. (Again, see previous link for more details.)

From the chrome docs here is what soft navigation means:

- The navigation is initiated by a user action.
- The navigation results in a visible URL change to the user, and a history change.
- The navigation results in a DOM change.

**Possible Solution to Your Question**

In my experience this typically comes down to how you have your server configured. It would be helpful to know what you're using to host your site. But ensure that you have a rewrite rule enabled. Here are a few examples of popular server technologies:

**Apache**
Add a rewrite rule to `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR] 
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
  RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
 
  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html 
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

**Nginx**
Add a rewrite rule to your vhosts config:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

**IIS**
Add a rewrite rule to the `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer> 
  <rewrite> 
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true"> 
        <match url=".*" /> 
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" /> 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" /> 
        </conditions> 
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" /> 
      </rule> 
    </rules> 
  </rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

**Helpful Links**

[Chrome Soft Navigations Experiment](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/soft-navigations-experiment)

[Angular Deployment Guide for Server Config Reference](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

[JavaScript History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)